# How to import a list of contacts to telegram from desktop application?

Tags: telegram

Is there a way to easily import a list of contacts to telegram from desktop application?

I found contacts.importContacts method in Telegram API, but don't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use TLSharp library in your desktop application, easily you can call contacts.importContacts method in this way:

```
client = new TelegramClient(apiId, apiHash);
await client.ConnectAsync();
var result = await client.GetContactsAsync();
```

and for example use the result variable in this way:

```
var user = result.users.lists
  .Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(TLUser))
  .Cast<TLUser>()
  .Where(x => x.first_name == textBox1.Text);
if (user.ToList().Count != 0)
{
    foreach (var u in user)
    await client.SendMessageAsync(new TLInputPeerUser() { user_id = u.id }, textBox1.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try Settings -> Advanced -> Export your telegram data, in the bottom of the window you will see a `JSON` switch
If you're on Mac OS and don't see `Advanced` option, then you can try Telegram Lite from Mac App Store

Answer (score 0):

```
var contactList = new TLVector<TLInputPhoneContact>();

            foreach (var mobile in mobileNoList)
            {
                contactList.lists.Add(new TLInputPhoneContact { first_name = mobile.First Name, last_name = mobile.LastName, phone =  mobile.MobileNo.ToString() });
            }

            var req = new TLRequestImportContacts()
            {
                contacts = contactList
            };

            try
            {
                var result = await client.SendRequestAsync<TLImportedContacts>(req);
```

Comment: A short comment to your code what it does / why / how it solves the problem would go a long way from one answer to a good answer

Comment: Apparently, there are some limitations on importing new contacts. The telegram had blocked me out for trying to import 24000 contacts at once.